# why Javascript showing output with setTimeout function sync and async?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
for(var i = 2;i >= 1;i--) {
  setTimeout(function (i) {
    console.log(i);
  },1000);
  console.log("hii");
}
```

**This code gives me output as**

- hii
- hii
- undefined
- undefined

Where as after using setTimeout in below format gives different output

```js
for(var i = 2;i >= 1;i--) {
  setTimeout(print(i),5000);
  console.log("hii");
}
function print(i) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

**This code gives me output as**

- 2
- hii
- 1
- hii

I don't understand why in second case code is executing synchronously.

Comment: You are executing  `print(i)` as you are looping. It does not return a funtion (callback). You need to run `setTimout(functionname OR anonymous function)` not `setTimeout(somefunction())`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there you have called the `print` function, it's not passed as a callback. In this situation, it will complete the execution of `print` function and then pass the return value as first argument to setTimeout.

This is what you are trying:-

```
for(var i = 2;i >= 1;i--) {
  setTimeout(print(i),5000);
  console.log("hii");
}
function print(i) {
  return function(){console.log(i)}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, you are passing a function that takes a single parameter, `i` to setTimeout , but setTimeout does not pass any arguments to that function (or any function for that matter) when it calls it. Hence `i` is undefined in that function and so `undefined` is outputted.

In the second example, you are calling print, and passing the result to setTimeout. But print is executing immediately, so that's why a number is outputted before "hii" each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

```js
for(var i = 2;i >= 1;i--) {
  setTimeout(function (i) {
    console.log(i);
  },1000);
  console.log("hii");
}
```

Javascript has a function-level scope and not a block-level scope. so when you call the `setTimeout` inside the for loop like below:

```
setTimeout(function (i) {
        console.log(i);
      },1000);
```

what happens is a local variable `i` is introduced which has not been set to any value and hence it returns `undefined` in JS.

in your second snippet the callback gets executed and returns value which is printed on screen